# Make a Bootstrap column adjust to the height of an adjacent column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want two bootstrap columns to alsways have equal size. This is the scenario:

[image]

I want the column with the text to be always equal in height to the picture on the left.

This is my markup (simplified):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8" id="brand-slider">
        <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
               <slides>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4" id="brand-aside">
        <div class="brand-aside-content">
          <text-content>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've read many similar topic on stack and elsewhere, but I did not find a viable solution. Most of them were convoluted in some way.

In a different project I was working on, I achieved this effect by suign a JS script that always calculated the height of one column and applied it to the adjacent column. However, I believe that there is a simpler solution.

Would appreciate your advice.

Comment: Post your full(unsimplified) code that is causing this. I will set it up according to that.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of solving this:

**CSS:**

Use `min-height` and center your content vertically.

**JS**

Get the height of all your columns, compare them to get the highest value, and apply that height to all of them.

*Your JS solution is the cleanest, the CSS may be simpler but you might end up adding height to both columns, or even not setting a min-height big enough for one of them and cutting content out*

Comment: Hi Aramii, I'm not sure min-height expressed in percent would work for floated elements. Bootstrap columns are floated.

Comment: It must be in px or some fixed value. since its verticall it won't break responsive, but if your content gets larger on small device you would need media queries. Anyways JS solution is the correct one on my opinion

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS 3 flexbox..

```
.equal, .equal > div[class*='col-'] {  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex:1 0 auto;
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/4Mk1bavvby

Comment: Thanks for putting together the demo. Unfortunately, you can see from it that this solution does not work. The objective is to have the content column have equal height to the image on the left. Sure, your solution extends both columns to equal height, but regardless  of what happens to the content. You see it in the demo. I'm inclined to think that the only viable solution would be JS.

Answer (score 0):

You can now take advantage of Cards for Bootstrap 4 in [constructing Masonry-like columns](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-columns).